# Unknown mystery error when running VBA for loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I am trying to use the following VBA sub to find the corresponding first column value for the initial negative values/last positive value of each subsequent column, but when i run it it immediately gave me a

> "400"

error. Do you guys know what are possible reasons?

```
Sub findzero()

For i = 225 To 335
    For j = 19 To 10018
        If Range(Cells(j, i)).Value < 0 Then
            Range(Cells(14, i)).Value = Range(Cells(j - 1, 1)).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: *a "400" error* - what is the error description and on what line does it appear?

Comment: it gave a dialog box just saying "400", no context, and a red box "X" warning sign

Comment: does [this](https://www.add-ins.com/support/microsoft-visual-basis-error-400.htm) help? ... or [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1721-visual-basic-error-400-a.html)...  is your sheet protected?

Comment: What version on xl do you have?

Comment: The fix doesn't help sadly since im using excel 2013 and the assistant thing isn't there from the beginning

Comment: Ohhh it seems when i get rid of "range..." and only leave cells there, and changed < to <= somehow the problem is solved... do you guys know why?

Comment: When referring to only one cell, either use range or cells but not both.  Range expects a range of cells or to be used alone when referring to single cell.

Comment: Funny thing is that I was in the middle of mentioning that and decided to abandon it ...  Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

When I run this, I'm getting a different error than you are.  I'm getting "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed."  I'm not quite sure why our messages are different, though.

At any rate, I don't think this is using the "Range" object (object?) correctly.  It either needs to be `Range(Cells(j,i),Cells(j,i)).Value`(selecting a "range" which spans only one cell) or just `Cells(j,i).`

```
For i = 225 To 335
    For j = 19 To 10018
        If Cells(j, i) < 0 Then
            Cells(14, i) = Cells(j - 1, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Or, alternately,

```
For i = 225 To 335
    For j = 19 To 10018
        If Range(Cells(j, i), Cells(j, i)).Value < 0 Then
            Range(Cells(14, i), Cells(14, i)).Value = Range(Cells(j - 1, 1), Cells(j - 1, 1)).Value
            Beep
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

I personally prefer the first way.  There may be a better way to do this, but I don't know what it would be.